# Security implications of static IP?

Tags: ip, remote-desktop

I need a static IP for a remote shutdown utility with my phone.
What are the security implications of setting IP to static?

I feel the "attacker knows your IP won't change" argument may be a overrated threat.
I use Norton 360 and VPN with Windows security center off (windows 7).

NB: The only port forward I have is a 5-digit UDP through the VPN.

Comment: I think the argument is better stated, "if an attacker finds a weakness, they can always return to your vulnerable port". That threat is up to you to accept or not.

Comment: Would it be so hard to find the vulnerable host again after a IP change? (VPN is always on and shuffles IP use)

Comment: For instance, if a scanning bot is looking for weaknesses, finds your vulnerable port and enters you into a registry, then your record in that registry will continue to be valid. It might not matter in your situation, but the argument you state has more context to it.

Comment: @schroeder what about posting that as an answer?